# Creating fillable form after windows login

Tags: c#, sql, windows, forms, authentication

I would like to create or ideally use a pre-made program that will start-up every time a user logs into our lab computer (Windows 10), I am asking for simple information such as name, type of experiment, etc. Ideally this form would be mandatory. I have read about using the Credentials Provider in windows, but my programming knowledge is frankly limited to Matlab and I have no experience with SQL, C# or creating any windows applications.

This question is probably to open-ended for this forum, but I have no idea where to start! Google searches only direct me to windows login-related issues :/

Any insight on possible ways of doing this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a windows form in C# with some text box entry fields then you can add the program to the windows startup items for all users (https://www.labnol.org/software/add-programs-to-windows-startup/13013/). If you're really at the beginning then you need to get visual studio community here (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) and then follow a windows forms tutorial (probably easier than WPF) here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd492132.aspx.